# what is wrong in the sentence "i was not born for being free"?

Tags: grammar

When I'm saying the sentence

> *I was not born for being free.*

Can I use 'didnt' in place of "was not"?

> *I did not born for being free.*

Comment: If you want to *inject* a 'do' verb, you *'take'* birth. So I **did** not **take** birth for [whatever reason]. However, '....being free' sounds a little odd to my ears. What you want to express?

Comment: @Maulik V I've never encountered *take birth*. Is this an IE idiom? I'd love to hear how it is used.

Comment: Yes! But more to do with *incarnation/avatar* though. The Lord Krishna *took birth* in the form of Koorm (Sanskrit) i.e. a turtle. Probably because when it is *god*, he has a *choice* to *take birth*. Humans are simply born, but gods, on their choices, take birth! @StoneyB

Answer (score 4):

The correct sentence would be

> I wasn't born to be free

**be born** is passive voice, and you can't use did/didn't with passive voice. The active voice form is **bear** so it would be grammatically correct to say

> My mother didn't bear me to be free

But it lacks the impact of the first sentence and it's not clear whether you or your mother will not be free.